# How to auto restart a command after it closes down?

Tags: bash

I am using rtmpdump to restream live video on my local network on nginx rtmp server. like this:

```
sudo rtmpdump -r "rtmp://123.45.6.7/live/" -a "live/" -f "LNX 14,0,0,125" -W "http://123.45.6.7/jwplayer.flash.swf[1] " -p "http://123.45.6.7/[2] " --live -y "livestream2" | avconv -i pipe:0 -y
-v:v info -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/
```

it works great on its own with no problem but once in a while the original source might flicker and it will cause the running command to quit, and I have to manually run the command again. Is there a way to make a script which will automatically detect if rtmpdump quit and there is no zombie command running and rerun the command?
I want to automate this process for about 4 live streams. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not loop it? A `while true; do sudo ..; done`?

Comment: dont know how to do it, bash scripts are my weakness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script with these contents:

```
#! /bin/bash
function INT_cleanup()
{
    kill `jobs -p`
    exit
}

trap INT_cleanup INT

# ${VAR-TEXT} means that TEXT is used if VAR is empty.

STREAM_START=$(($1))
STREAM_END=$(($2))
for ((COUNT=STREAM_START; COUNT<=STREAM_END;COUNT++))
do
    while true #Infinite loop
    do
        rtmpdump -r "rtmp://123.45.6.7/live/" -a "live/" -f "LNX 14,0,0,125" -W \
            "http://123.45.6.7/jwplayer.flash.swf[1] " \
            -p "http://123.45.6.7/[2] " --live -y "livestream$COUNT" | 
        avconv -i pipe:0 -y -v:v info -vcodec copy \
            -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live$COUNT/
    done &
done
```

Or

```
#! /bin/bash
function INT_cleanup()
{
    kill `jobs -p`
    exit
}

trap INT_cleanup INT

count=0
while [[ $count < 10 ]] # Try 10 times
do
    rtmpdump -r "rtmp://123.45.6.7/live/" -a "live/" -f "LNX 14,0,0,125" -W "http://123.45.6.7/jwplayer.flash.swf[1] " -p "http://123.45.6.7/[2] " --live -y "livestream2" | avconv -i pipe:0 -y -v:v info -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/
    count=$((count + 1))
done
```

in a file, call it `stream.sh`, make it executable:

```
chmod +x stream.sh
```

and run it:

```
sudo ./stream.sh 1 3
```

To kill the script, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. The first is an infinite loop, the second runs for 10 iterations.

Comment: Awesome this works great. ctrl+c actually restarts the rtmpdump command and its a good way to test, but ctrl+z totally stops the script. When I run rtmpdump command, it takes over my terminal screen with output. would it be able to run the script in the background?

Comment: @bran In that case, Ctrl-C reaches the `rtpdump` command, so you can trap the signal. Is the output of `rtpdump` important? If not, run the script like so: `sudo ./script > /dev/null &`

Comment: @bran also, how do the links to the streams vary? You could make it a parameter.

Comment: the only two things that varries are the "livestream2" from rtmpdump and link part of the avconv command where "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/" goes up to 'live3'. would it be possible to automate it?

Comment: @bran have a look at it now. I have only changed the first example, you can easily modify the second based on it.

Comment: Wow, this is insane, thanks so much for effort I feel like I learned quite a bit about bash. Maybe I should finally spend some time learning it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script. I used it to respawn AWN dock. It works ok but I advise you to test it before heavily use

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # This script is a simple respawn deamon for those of us who dont want
 # to deal with the /etc/event.d, monit etc...
 # Usage: sh respawn.sh [program] [sleep time]

 while [ true ]
 do
       sleep $2
       if ps ax | grep -v grep | $1 > /dev/null
       then
            echo $1": Stopped. Restarting in "$2" seconds."
       else
            $1 &
       fi
  done
```

Comment: Suggest using `pgrep` over `ps | grep`. And we don't need `test` (or `[ ]`) around `true`.

Comment: Thanks Kenn, this is similar to what muru posted, both useful.